# Disjointness of Fibonacci-like sequences.

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, fibonacci-numbers

Consider two different integers $d\neq c>2$ and the two Fibonacci-like recursions (notice the negative signs):
$$ a(i)=ca(i-1)-a(i-2)\text{ and } b(i)=db(i-1)-b(i-2),$$
where $a(0)=b(0)=0$ and $a(1)=b(1)=1$.

I want to know if its possible to have $a(i)=b(j)$ for some $i,j>2$. Moreover, what is the smallest number $N$ for which every number bigger than $N$ is in the orbit of some sequence as these with the restrictions above?

Numerical evidence suggests both claims above are true, but I don't know how to show it. This seems like something that should be well known, references would be appreciated.

**About the restrictions**:

- I consider $c>2$ becase the sequence for $c=2$ is simply $0,1,2,3\dots$ and both questions above become trivial.
- Sequences are strictly increasing so for disjointness we need $i>1$. If $i=2$ then $a(2)=c-1$ and the claims above become both trivial as we vary $c$. I think the minimal interesting example is $i=3$.
- Perhaps I should make some more assumptions. Will report back as soon as I know.

Comment: Why do you think "every positive integer is in the orbit of a such a sequence for a unique $c$"?  That will be true either if $c=2$ or if you are allowed to consider $a(2)$, but you seem to exclude both of these

Comment: Yes - $a(i)$ is a strictly increasing sequence for $c \ge 2$ so its is clear that if restricted to $c>2$ and $i>2$ then $4,5,6,7$ (for example) never appear as $a(i)$ in any such sequence.

Comment: You're both right. A previous edit of the post clarified that I expect the claim only to hold for numbers bigger than another, for example $8$. Perhaps the question would be which would be this number. I'll edit accordingly.